# Verifying Implicit Differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I have edited my post once more. Assume $\eta(x,t)$ is evaluate first at x=0 and then at $t=t-\frac{x}{1+v}$ where $v$ is a constant. This gives us
$$\eta(0,t-\frac{x}{1+v})$$
now i wish to take $\frac{d}{dx}$ of the above so:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\eta(\underbrace{0}_\textrm{a},\underbrace{t-\frac{x}{1+v}}_\textrm{b})=\frac{d\eta(a,b)}{da}\frac{da}{dx}+\frac{d\eta(a,b)}{db}\frac{db}{dx}$$
since $\frac{da}{dx}=0$ and $\frac{db}{dx}=-\frac{1}{1+v}$ we have
$$=\frac{d\eta(a,b)}{db}(-\frac{1}{1+v})$$
but what is $\frac{d}{db}?$,

Is there anything that prevents me from wtitting above as:
$$=\frac{d\eta(a,b)}{dt}\frac{dt}{db}(-\frac{1}{1+v})=\eta_t(a,b)(1)(-\frac{1}{1+v})$$

or for that matter:
$$=\frac{d\eta(a,b)}{dx}\frac{dx}{db}(-\frac{1}{1+v})=\eta_x(a,b)(-(1+v))(-\frac{1}{1+v})=\eta_x(a,b)$$
 If this is incorrect, where  am I confused?
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thank You,

Comment: I think  using the symbol $\eta$ to denote two quite different functions is a mistake. It certainly leads to endless confusion. Call the LHS $\phi(x,t)$ and then rework and see if your confusion is resolved.

Comment: Thank You. I have reduced the problem to a bare minimum of understanding a derivative, just taking derivative of the RHS of an expression I had in the earlier post.

Comment: Until you specify the function $\eta(a,b)$ there is no way of telling what its partial derivative with respect to the second variable is. Full stop.

Comment: I do not know explicitly function $\eta(a,b)$. All I know is that it would be a continuous and at least once differentiable function. I am not looking for explicit derivative, the result i am looking for would be in terms of $\eta(a,b)$ or rather its derivatives. Hope it helps.

Comment: In terms of $\eta$ the answer is $\frac{\partial\eta(a,b)}{\partial b}$.

Comment: Thank You for all the comments. I guess that is the best I can get in terms of unknown function $\eta$.

Comment: I have edited the post once more further rephrasing the question and looking for some clarification. Thank You.